# How can i include ssl certificate in post request javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ssl, post

How can i make a post request to an endpoint with a ssl certificate included, in typescript or javascript. I am doing this for a project am working on in ionic 3.

Comment: You want to *include* the cert in the request?

Comment: Why would you want to send the cert?

Comment: Including certificate inside of a request... sounds like 'interesting' idea

Comment: @MatusDubrava Those Javascript Framework are getting too far haha

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include an SSL certificate in a request unless you're meaning uploading the file to send to an endpoint.

You can send a request **over** SSL by sending it to a secure endpoint e.g. `https://somerequesturl.com/proccess-form.php`